# Alternative uses for RockShox fork oil

Tags: fork, suspension, lubricant

I currently have a small bottle of red RockShox 15wt fork oil left over. As I no longer own a RockShox fork, this oil seems pretty useless to me. (Fox specifies different oil weights, and I can't figure out whether the oil would be ok to service my new 34 Rhythm fork. Preliminary research ranges from "usable in the lower legs" to "better safe than sorry, so use only Fox oil".)

Suppose I can't use the oil for the lower leg service of my Fox fork - are there any reasonable bike-related use cases for the oil? Probably the oil is too thin as a chain lubricant, right? Or should I rather try to find someone who actually needs it for his/her fork?

*As an aside: There are loads of questions on the internet about the reverse case: "What oil can I use instead of the manufacturer-recommended oil?" But I can't seem to find an answer to my question.*

Comment: Give it away to someone who does have the fork?  Send it with the fork when you passed the bike on ?

Comment: The second option would actually be my favourite, but AFAIK the buyer would probably let a shop do the fork service, so I'm not sure if the oil would be useful to him...

Comment: Fox Rhythm 34’s specify 10wt oil for lower servicing. So you don’t want to use it for that.

Answer (score 1):

Offering your remaining oil on a local marketplace might be a good idea. While servicing an older RockShox suspension fork, I spilled out the original oil and needed to replace it. Costs were greater than $10 for sourcing this. My LBS offered me a slightly different weight from their old stock, so I got lucky. During the search I would have appreciated picking up a slight amount of shock designated oil / lubricant locally.